# mongoose with rxjs - can´t catch error on promise resolve

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, rxjs

i´m using mongoose in my node.js - express. In my schema model i´m using the package `mongoose-unique-validator` to check that user email is unique, if the email already exist i would get and error `ValidationError: User validation failed: email: Error, expected "email" to be unique. Value: "example@example.com"` (which is fine). i decide to turn my promises from mongoose to `rxjs observables` this way:

**controller.ts**

```
      creatUser(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        from(bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10))
          .pipe(
            mergeMap((hash) => {
              const avatartPath = this.utilities.generateImgPath(req);
              const user = this.userAdatper.userAdatper(req.body, { password: hash, avatar: avatartPath });
              return of(new User(user).save()).pipe(catchError((error) => of(error)));
            })
          )
          .subscribe(
            (user) => {
              console.log() // Promise is resolve here on the validation error return an empty object
              res.status(201).send(user);
            },
            (err) => {
              console.log(err);
              res.status(500);
              const error = new Error(`Internal Server Error - ${req.originalUrl}`);
              next(error);
            }
          );
      }

**Schema**

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  user_rol: {
    type: String,
    default: 'subscriber',
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    requiered: true,
  },
  fullName: {
    type: String,
    requiered: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    requiered: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    requiered: true,
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String,
    requiered: true,
  },
  favorites: [
    {
      type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
      ref: 'ArcadeItems',
    },
  ],
  updatedOn: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
```

but for some reason if the promise fail, it resolve on the success callback after subscription returning and empty object and no the error callback, try to implement `catchError()` from rxjs operators but no success.

Comment: What's the problem? `bcrypt.hash` isn't failing?

Comment: in case i insert and email that is already on the db `new User(user).save()` the plugin `mongoose-unique-validator` is gonna throw and error, i try to catch the error in the `pipe` or in the subscription error callback but for some reason observable is completed as success.

Comment: You `catchError` and return a successful stream, so that's as expected? Also, you keep typing "and" when you mean "an" - is that on purpose? It's very confusing.

Comment: i found the reason why, i replace the `of(new User(user).save())` for `from(new User(user).save())` for promises to observables `from()` is the correct operator

Comment: `catchError(err => of(err))` turns an error stream into a successfull stream that emits the error as an object to the observer's `.next` callback.

Comment: @MrkSef you are right i fix that also and changed for `throwError()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `of(new User(user)...)` for `from(new User(user)...)` and on `cathError()` return `throwError(error)`

```
creatUser(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        from(bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10))
          .pipe(
            mergeMap((hash) => {
              const avatartPath = this.utilities.generateImgPath(req);
              const user = this.userAdatper.userAdatper(req.body, { password: hash, avatar: avatartPath });
              return from(new User(user).save()).pipe(catchError((error) => throwError(error)));
            })
          )
          .subscribe(
            (user) => {
              console.log() // Promise is resolve here on the validation error return an empty object
              res.status(201).send(user);
            },
            (err) => {
              console.log(err);
              res.status(500);
              const error = new Error(`Internal Server Error - ${req.originalUrl}`);
              next(error);
            }
          );
      }
```